# RPi3 model won't display anything. May had short circuit it accidentally. is there any solution?

Tags: pi-3

Red led ON, green led continuously blinking. i touched it when i had already switch off the power to unplug but i felt tingling sensation. the pi won't boot up afterwards. any solution? do i have to buy a new one?

Comment: It sounds like a new one.

Comment: do you mean buying a new pi?

Comment: Please follow the troubleshooting link: https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

Pi is fine. i full formatted the sd card not just quick format. somehow the short circuit corrupted the sd card.